# How to extract list data by skipping position in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below list and want to extract data by skipping 3 positions (list) of each as per example.

Code Tried:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    print (data[i])
    i+= 3

i = 0

while i < len(data):
    item = data[i]
    print (item)
    if item == data[i]:
        print (item)
        i += 3
```

Expected:

```
['1', 'DURVANKUR', 'Durvankur A wing', '', '0', '1', '0', '21', '1', '0', '30']
['2', 'DURVANKUR', 'Durvankur B wing', '', '0', '1', '0', '15', '1', '0', '70']
```

Comment: `data[::3]` will slice what you want.

Comment: @KevinFang, you could make that an answer if you explain it a bit more

Comment: tried but not getting

Comment: @user10468005 it's `data[::4]` actually, you could probably provide a more readable example.

Comment: Yep `data[::4]` is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range` accepts a stride argument that you can use to skip however many lines that you need to skip

```
for i in range(0, len(data), 3):
    print(data[i])
```

You could also use slicing to get every 3rd element:

```
data_slice = data[::3]
for entry in data_slice:
    print(entry)
```

In your first example, `i` was being reset to the next value determined by `range` regardless of your attempts to add 3 to it. In your second example you print `data[i]` for all values of `i`. That's why neither of those attempts gave you the expected output